# CSS Drop Down Hover List creating extra margins

Tags: css, list

I'm currently designing the following site:

http://www.ultimate-punch.com/

I have a simple categories hover drop down menu (the green box) however it's creating both top and left space and I can't figure out why. Here's the HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="main_nav_left">
<ul>
    <li>Categories&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x25BC;
        <ul>
        <? while ($incr_categories != $count_categories) { ?>
            <a href="category.php?cat=<? echo $CATEGORIES[$incr_categories][0]; ?>"><li><? echo strtoupper($CATEGORIES[$incr_categories][0]); ?></li></a>

            <? $incr_categories++;
            } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#main_nav_left {
    width: 240px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#main_nav_left li {
    line-height:50px;
}
#main_nav_left ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type:none;
    color: #fff;    
    background-color: #59af56;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
#main_nav_left ul li ul{
    padding: 0px;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: 20px;
}
#main_nav_left ul li ul li {
    background-color: #7bc979;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 26px;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
    -moz-transition: all .8s;
    transition: all .8s;
}
#main_nav_left li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#main_nav_left ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #59af56;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s;
    -moz-transition: all .8s;
    transition: all .8s;
}
```

Can't figure out why it's doing that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ul` has a margin imposed by the browser, so the display breaks. You can apply the following rule to it to make it fall into place:

```
.main_nav_left ul { margin: 1px 0 0 0 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked for the top space, but still not sure about the left!

Comment: Like Vector says below, the browser adds padding to the `ul` be default. Adding a `padding: 0` on the `.main_nav_left ul` rule should remove that extra space

Answer (score 0):

There is a default margin on the UL that is causing space above it. Not sure about the space to the left. You should look into using a reset or normalize stylesheet.

Comment: How would you go about normalizing the stylesheet?